# Cassandra CQL column slice and read path confusion

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am wondering how's column slicing in CQL `WHERE` clause affects read performance. Does Cassandra have some optimization, which is able to only fetch specific columns with the value or have to retrieve all the columns of a row and check one after another? e.g.: I have a primary key as (key1, key2), key2 is the clustering key. I only want to find columns that match a certain key2, say value2?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra saves the data as cells - each value for a key+column is a cell. If you save several values for the key in once they will be placed together in same file. Also, since cassandra writes to sstables, you can have several values saved for same key-column/cell in different files, and cassandra will read all of them and return you the last written one, until comperssion or repair is occured, and irrelevant values are deleted.

Good article about deletes/reads/tombstones:
http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html

Comment: I am reading [this article](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ReadPathForUsers), it says differently:  We then scan the partition index, which will provide the offset in the SSTable where we can find the data associated with our partition key.
We then read the data from the in-memory MemTable, and merge this with the data from the SSTables. Data is merged cell by cell, with the timestamp for each cell being compared and the latest timestamp selected. Tombstones are ignored.

Comment: About tombstones -  they do not ignored it in the way you think they are. Example: You have a key, and you've inserted/updated it 3 times, and afterwards deleted it. So, theoretically, you can have 4 "values" for this key - 3 values and tombstone. When you request a value for that key, the engine will go through all the 4 "values" and determine the latest one, and if this is tombstone you will get no rows/values, but this doesn't means that the row wasn't read by Cassandra.